Proxy error - HTTP error code 400 within burpsuite when using whatsapp websockets
I am testing Whatsapp web within burpsuite. I am performing the connection process via the qr code that is generated within whatsapp web and capturing this traffic within burpsuite in order to utilise the captured cookie and websocket key so I can replay the attack and gain access to the whatsapp web account (my account for testing purposes). When I send the request to burpsuites repeater tab and replay the the request I am met with a HTTP 400 error code, and the connection is unsuccesful even though I seemingly have the correct parameters needed in order to authorise a connection. I have attached an image of the request and response within burpsuites repeater, does anyone know what may be causing the issue here? Is the request code written in an incorrect format? Thanks
P.s the browser being used is the burp suite built in browser chromium if that makes any difference. I have also reset burp to default settings and deleted any cache and cookies within the browser which may have been affecting the request
